# Remote config with Angular

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-remote-config

how are you?

I'm trying to fetch a configuration that I've created in Firebase's remote config with my **Angular 15 application.**

The configuration is named "AllowedUsers."
[Remote config IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUG5z.png)

In my application, I already have Firebase configured because I use it for other things, but now I need to fetch this configuration and I haven't been able to do so.

**app.module**

```
    imports: [
        ...
        AppRoutingModule,
        provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebase)),
        provideFirestore(() => getFirestore()),
        provideRemoteConfig(() => getRemoteConfig()),
    ],
```

**service**

```
import { RemoteConfig } from '@angular/fire/remote-config';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyService {

   private readonly firestore:Firestore = inject(Firestore)
   private readonly remoteConfig:RemoteConfig = inject(RemoteConfig)

   getRemoteConfig():void{
    console.log('config',this.remoteConfig);
   }

  getFeatures():Observable<IFeature[]>{
    const featureRef = collection(this.firestore,this.collectionName)
    return collectionData(featureRef,{idField:'id'}) as Observable<IFeature[]>
  }
}
```

**package json:** @angular/fire: 7.6.1

I'm not sure if the way I'm using is correct, but I haven't found another one. (The ones I found were outdated with modules that no longer exist in Angular 15).

I've tried different methods and imports, and what I'm hoping for is to retrieve the value of my remote configuration.

the console log print:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHLqu.png)

Answer (score 0):

According to the compatibility guide [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire#compatibility), I think you need to install @angular/fire version 7.5 to be compatible with your Angular 15 application. Then you will be able to get the remote config from this import `import { RemoteConfig } from '@angular/fire/remote-config';`

Comment: I have just updated the code with more information.

When I print this.remoteConfig, I am unable to see my remote configuration ("AllowedUsers") anywhere.
Remember that I set this configuration in the Firebase console's remote config.